# Total of Same Customer ID from a Single DB Table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with multiple customers.  Each customer has a unique ID.  Example, only one customer has ID as CustomerID = 100.  The customer can be entered into the table numerous times but the CustomerID will be associated with a different ItemOrdered.  The part of the table being questioned is, for example:

```
CustomerID              ItemOrdered

100                     ABCDE
100                     EFGHI
100                     JKLMN
200                     OPQRST
200                     UVWXY
300                     ZABCD
```

I have tried `SUM, COUNT COUNT(DISTINCT  )` and cannot get the correct answer from the query.

The correct answer from above would be

```
CustomerID 100  3
CustomerID 200  2
CustomerID 300  1
```

It is the 3, 2, 1 that I am after.  Any help or point in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select CustomerID,Count(*) as cnt
from Table
Group by CustomerID
```

Comment: Thank you bummi - it was so simple but so far.  It worked just great.